# SQL Alchemy Flask Delete

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

If I run the following query:

```
 a = db.session.query(Submission).filter_by(id=todelid,deletioncode=todelcode).count()
```

and I print a, it returns 1.

However when I run the following:

```
db.session.delete(db.session.query(Submission).filter_by(id=todelid,deletioncode=todelcode))
```

OR

```
a = db.session.query(Submission).filter_by(id=todelid,deletioncode=todelcode).delete()
```

it does not delete from the database.
How can I make it delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without [`session.commit()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#committing) you are actually just [marking objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#deleting) for deletion:

```
db.session.query(Submission).filter_by(id=todelid,deletioncode=todelcode).delete()
db.session.commit()
```